# Twitter OAuth authentication VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to use a twitter app I've created to tweet from various accounts.

I've used the Postman application to access "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", I supplied all the relevant details (apart from "oauth_callback" which it didn't seem to need) which returns the "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret" successfully.

I then used Postman again to access "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize" using the details I obtained above which works.

My problem is trying to get the first part working in VB.NET.

I suspect my issue is with the signature as I copied the headers from Postman into my code and it worked.

Has anyone got the correct code for this?

Thanks, Andy

```
Dim str_oauth_signature As String = String.Empty

Dim str_base_format As String = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}"

Dim str_base = String.Format(str_base_format,
oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_nonce,
oauth_signature_method,
oauth_timestamp,
oauth_token,
oauth_version)

str_base = String.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(str_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(str_base))

Dim str_composite_key As String = String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret))

Dim hasher As HMACSHA1 = New HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str_composite_key))

Using hasher
    str_oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str_base)))
End Using
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net

Comment: Thanks @FloatingKiwi but I've already followed that example and I'm still having issues. The signature that code is generating is taking the param "status" which I don't use in my method. Any ideas how I would generate the signature specifically for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"?